# try to get the children of TabViewItem, but always returns nothing

Tags: c#, uwp

my code to get the children of TabViewItem

[image]

```
var v=VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(aTableViewItem);
```

v always returns 0

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(someControl);
```

works for Button StackPanel etc, but does not work for TableViewItem

[image]

Is there a way to get the Children Count of TableViewItem?

Comment: When is `GetChildrenCount` method called?  could you make sure TabViewItem is loaded?

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT after public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent(); I try to call VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(someControl), it works for all other items except TableViewItem(of course h82258652 mentioned TabView also needs to process in special way)

Comment: I just update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try to get the children of TabViewItem, but always returns nothing

I'm afraid you can not get children when call `GetChildrenCount` after `InitializeComponent`, because the TabView control has not loaded, The MainPage class associates itself with the corresponding XAML by calling the generated `InitializeComponent` method in its constructor. please try to call `GetChildrenCount` in TabView loaded event, for my testing it works well.

```
private void TabViewItem_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MyTabItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `VisualTreeHelper` to do this. The relationship between `TabView` and `TabViewItem` is logic, not visual.

If you use the WinUI:

```
var count = TabView.TabItems.Count;
```

If you use the Windows Community Toolkit:

```
var count = TabView.Items.Count;
```

Comment: thanks! but I hope to get the children of TableViewItem rather than t the children of TabView